# Chaining RxJava observables with callbacks/listeners

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I am using Retrofit with Observables, and would like to chain the observables. Usually it works well with functions like `map()` or `flatMap()`, since the `api` returns an Observable that does the task. But in this case I have to do the following:

1. getKey() from the `api`
2. Use the returned key in another library `Foo` and wait for the callback to be called.
3. When the callback returns, send the result to the `api`.

I'd like this to be a single chained call so that I just have to subscribe once. I'm guessing I can use `merge()` or `join()` or something, but wasn't sure what the best approach would be to handle the callback.

Is there a way to make this better? This is what I have so far:

```
api.getKey().subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
   @Override
   public void call(String key) {
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      foo.setAwesomeCallback(new AwesomeCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onAwesomeReady(String awesome) {
            api.sendAwesome(awesome)
                    .subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
                       @Override
                       public void call(Void aVoid) {
                           handleAwesomeSent();
                       }
                    });
         }
      });
      foo.makeAwesome();
   }
});
```

Comment: Where is the key used?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adapting clemp6r's solution, here is another one that needs neither `Subjects` nor nested `Subscriptions`:

```
api.getKey().flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<String> call(String key) {

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>(){

            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                Foo foo = new Foo();
                foo.setAwesomeCallback(new AwesomeCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAwesomeReady(String awesome) {
                        if (! subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onNext(awesome);
                            subscriber.onComplete();
                        }
                    }
                });
                foo.makeAwesome();
            } 
        });
}).flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<String> call(String awesome) {
        return sendAwesome(awesome);
   }
}).subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Void aVoid) {
        handleAwesomeSent();
    }
});
```

In general I think it always possibly to wrap any callback based asynchronous operation in an `Observable` using `Observable.create()`.

Comment: This is very helpful

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a PublishSubject to transform the callback-based API to an observable.

Try something like that (not tested):

```
api.getKey().flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
   @Override
   public Observable<String> call(String key) {
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
      foo.setAwesomeCallback(new AwesomeCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onAwesomeReady(String awesome) {
            subject.onNext(awesome);
            subject.onComplete();
         }
      });
      foo.makeAwesome();

      return subject;
   }
}).flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
   @Override
   public Observable<String> call(String awesome) {
       return sendAwesome(awesome);
   }
}).subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Void aVoid) {
        handleAwesomeSent();
    }
});
```

Comment: You will want to call subject.onComplete() after your subject.onNext(awesome) so the Observable chain will complete.

Comment: `PublishSubject` is not required, you can use `flatMap` + `Observable.create()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Api api = new Api() {
  @Override Single<String> getKey() {
    return Single.just("apiKey");
  }
};

api.getKey()
    .flatMap(key -> Single.<String>create( singleSubscriber -> {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setAwesomeCallback(awesome -> {
          try { singleSubscriber.onSuccess(awesome);}
          catch (Exception e) { singleSubscriber.onError(e); }
        });
        foo.makeAwesome();
    }))
    .flatMapCompletable(
        awesome -> Completable.create(completableSubscriber -> {
          try {
            sendAwesome(awesome);
            completableSubscriber.onCompleted();
          } catch (Exception e) { completableSubscriber.onError(e); }
        }))
    .subscribe(this::handleAwesomeSent, throwable -> { });
```

[**See gist for full anonymous class example**](https://gist.github.com/ersin-ertan/a3c6ac7951297ae3c20055d20ff7899b)

This implementation adapts david.mihola answer by making use of `Single` and `Completable` types along with the `flatMapCompletable()`, while being type safe/specific.